# How to force a ndarray show in normal way instead of scientific notation?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, scientific-notation

I'm trying to print a ndarray on the screen. But python always shows it in scientific notation, which I don't like. For a scalar we can use

```
>>> print '%2.4f' %(7.47212470e-01)
0.7472
```

But how to do that for a numpy.ndarray like this :

```
[[  7.47212470e-01   3.71730070e-01   1.16736538e-01   1.22172891e-02]
 [  2.79279640e+00   1.31147152e+00   7.43946656e-02   3.08162255e-02]
 [  6.93657970e+00   3.14008688e+00   1.02851599e-01   3.96611266e-02]
 [  8.49295040e+00   3.94730094e+00   8.99398479e-02   7.60969188e-02]
 [  2.01849250e+01   8.62584092e+00   8.75722302e-02   6.17109672e-02]
 [  2.22570710e+01   1.00291292e+01   1.20918359e-01   1.07250131e-01]
 [  2.82496660e+01   1.27882133e+01   1.08438172e-01   1.58723714e-01]
 [  5.89170270e+01   2.55268510e+01   1.31990966e-01   1.61599514e-01]]
```

The method .astype(float) does not change the result, and .round(4) returns:

```
[[  7.47200000e-01   3.71700000e-01   1.16700000e-01   1.22000000e-02]
 [  2.79280000e+00   1.31150000e+00   7.44000000e-02   3.08000000e-02]
 [  6.93660000e+00   3.14010000e+00   1.02900000e-01   3.97000000e-02]
 [  8.49300000e+00   3.94730000e+00   8.99000000e-02   7.61000000e-02]
 [  2.01849000e+01   8.62580000e+00   8.76000000e-02   6.17000000e-02]
 [  2.22571000e+01   1.00291000e+01   1.20900000e-01   1.07300000e-01]
 [  2.82497000e+01   1.27882000e+01   1.08400000e-01   1.58700000e-01]
 [  5.89170000e+01   2.55269000e+01   1.32000000e-01   1.61600000e-01]]
```

I just simply want the  0.7472  0.3717  etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`numpy.set_string_function`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_string_function.html) function can be used to change the string representation of arrays.

You can also use [`numpy.set_print_options`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to change the precision used by default and turn off reporting of small numbers in scientific notation.

From the examples for `set_print_options`:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
>>> print np.array([1.123456789])
[ 1.1235]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the numpy arrays but I was simply facing the same problem while doing a project in Python.

Take a look at the Decimal class provided http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html .

I don't know if it's provided in numpy though.

Comment: Thank you ~ That's another useful point. But now I just want to improve the output without annoying loops. If there is no straight solution, I'll just leave it to the time.

Comment: Actually there would be no annoying loops. Just import Decimal and for the printing just write print Decimal(ndarray[i]) .                     It all depends on you though :)