# Convert 2-d array of strings to float in python_removing scientific notation

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, scientific-notation

How can I convert scientific notations to the original format when I use numpy.astype in x array? Here's my code:

```
with open ('outfile.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    reader_list = list(reader)
    reader_array = array(reader_list)
    x = reader_array[:,5].astype(np.float)

    #original array:
    print reader_array[:,5]

    #converted to float
    print x

#original array:
['-0.00041955436132607246' '-0.00036612800229292086'  '0.00022313364860991641' ..., '73.418371245304215' '73.417384428365267'  '73.416718169781149'] 

#converted to float
[ -4.19554361e-04  -3.66128002e-04   2.23133649e-04 ...,   7.34183712e+01    7.34173844e+01   7.34167182e+01]
```

To be more specific, I want to convert array of strings to floats, but keep the same format as the original array, and do some analysis on it:

```
#find row number of max value in column 1: (This piece works fine)
max_index = where(reader_array[:,1] == max(reader_array[:,1]))

#take last element in column 5: (This one is also fine)
total_ = (reader_array[(len(reader_array[:,5])-1),5])

#find row number where element in column 5 is equal to 0.1*total_: (here's the problem!)
0.1_index = where((reader_array[:,5]) == (total_)*0.1)
```

So I think changing the strings to floats but with the same format as the original array allows multiplying array members by another float (0.1 here).

Please note that the value (0.1*total_) may not match any of the rows values in column 5, which I have to think how to solve. But I cannot progress without being able to compare rows with (0.1*total_).

I appreciate if someone can give a hint how to approach please.

Comment: This is more a print problem, your question is probably answered here: [How to force a ndarray show in normal way instead of scientific notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4205259/832621)

Comment: Numpy is not enough because float64 only has ~15 significant digits, and your numbers have 17 significant digits. You can use [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/decimal.html), or [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, the OP has issues like type differences. The question has nothing to do with printing per se (though it _does_ sound like that, the printing issue is just a manifestation of a misunderstanding).

Comment: @SaulloCastro, Well, not really, I had already tried printing options but that was not my question here. As Henry Gomersall pointed, my problem was with types. I may need to add more clarification for my later questions. Thanks.

Comment: @GustavBertram, Thanks for pointing to Decimal.

Comment: @PyLearner Sorry if I misunderstood your point. Should we ask for reopening?

Comment: It's alright for me as my problem is solved. But may be helpful for someone else as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're intrinsically limited by the fact that floating point numbers are stored using [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). You can't have arbitrary precision floating points, so in your case, you can't expect them to necessarily be exactly the same as a string representation.

However, in your case, the more pressing issue is that want to compare a string to a float, so of course they are going to be different. Python is dynamically, but [strongly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_typed_programming_language) typed.

Given both the above points, you need to better define your problem. Why do you need to compare with an array of strings? (what does this even mean!?)

Can you test for closeness rather than equality once you have your data types sorted out (e.g. using `numpy.close`)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your cm. Hinting 'closeness' made me think about that and finally found the solution using defining a function to find the nearest point.