# Convert to np.array, some values automatically being divided

Tags: python

I'm converting a list of strings into a list of lists, and then converting that list into a np.array.  The format of each list 5 element array within the np.array of arrays is [latitude, longitude, elevation, index, classifier].  The classifier is `1` if the elevation is above 0.00 (land) or `0` if the elevation is 0.00 (sea).

I've just noticed something strange, which is that list before being converted to an np.array has the correct values for each entry, ie:

```
[-33.765, 151.303, 49.227, 1373, 1],
[-33.765, 151.305, 0.0, 1374, 0]
```

where after being converted to an np.array, entries that have a classifier value of `1` (land) have been represented using e, whereas sea entries have remained the same, ie:

```
[  -33.792   151.402     0.     3635.        0.   ]
[ -3.37950000e+01   1.50900000e+02   7.75430000e+01   3.63600000e+03
   1.00000000e+00]
```

I'm not sure even where to begin to try to figure out why this could/would happen.  Is this some functionality of numpy arrays that I don't yet understand?

It's just taking in a .txt file containing geodesic coords in this format:

-33.750 151.025 90.882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e` represents scientific notation. I am not sure why this only happens with the land case, but [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205259/how-to-force-a-ndarray-show-in-normal-way-instead-of-scientific-notation) could be helpful in setting up `numpy.set_print_options` with `suppress=True` to force floating-point formatting.